# For which values, $a$ satsfies that $(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 + ax_2y_3 + ax_3y_2$ is an inner product in $R_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For which values, $a$ satsfies that $(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3 + ax_2y_3 + ax_3y_2$ is an inner product in $R_3$

---

I looked at the properties of inner product, and it seems that only the the property that satisfies: 
$$
(x,x) \geq 0
$$

May help.

But i got:

$$
(x,x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 +ax_2x_3 + ax_3x_2 \geq 0
$$

Getting:

$$
a \geq \frac{-x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}{2x_2x_3}
$$

But the answers say:

$$
|a| < 1
$$

How did they get this and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 +2ax_2x_3 =x_1^2+(x_2+ax_3)^2+(1-a^2)x_3^2$$

**Alternately,** the above is a quadratic form. Write the correspoding symmetric matrix, and check when the eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: I think we can use Sylvester criteria, its easier, isnt it? and thank you

Comment: @Alon If you go for the matrix approach, the eigenvalues are trivial to calculate, so in this case Sylvester criteria doesn't look easier. Note that $$\det(xI-a)= \det \begin{pmatrix}X-1&0&0\\0&X-1&-a\\0&-a&X-1\end{pmatrix}=(X-1) \det \begin{pmatrix}X-1&-a\\-a&X-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Or just eyeball the original matrix: $1$ is obvious, as is $1+a$, and the last eigenvalue can be obtained either by subtracting the third column from the second or by examining the trace.

Comment: You are right, just, can you explain how the trace help in finding the third eigenvalue?

Comment: @Alon The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace. Now if you know all but one, the trace can tell you which is the missing one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$(x,y)=x^T\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&a\\0&a&1\end{pmatrix}y$$

Comment: Ok, i used Sylvester criteria to determine positive definite and conclude alpha as needed, thank you.